# Situation pattern recognition and solution generation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What we have:

1. Ontology information on our current system (entities, properties, relations) saved in graph db.
2. IF THEN Rules about entities, properties, relations.
3. Current task.

**Ontology information**

Tom has a car.

Helen has phone.

Tom is 20 years old.

Helen is 30 years old.

Tom is a friend of Helen.

**Rules (patterns)**

IF (X has car AND Y has phone and X older than 18 AND Y older than 18 AND X is a friend of Y), THEN -> They can start taxi business.

Current Task

Generate any business opportunities for Tom. Particularly, the system must recognize the situation pattern, so it can be matched with the rule. On the pattern base the solution (projected on the current situation) must be generated:

As long as Tom and Helen are friends, they are both older than 18, Tom has a car and Helen has phone, -> Tom can start Taxi service business together with Helen.

My question: Can I implement that with neo4j (or use it as a module for such system)? If so, where can I find the related usecase or example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent the example you describe like this (using Cypher):

```
CREATE (tom:Person)
SET tom.name = "Tom",
    tom.age  = 20
CREATE (helen:Person)
    SET helen.name = "Helen",
        helen.age  = 30
CREATE (tom)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(helen)
CREATE (c:Car {desc: "2015 Red Honda Fit"})
CREATE (tom)-[:HAS_CAR]->(c)
CREATE (p:Phone {desc: "iPhone 6s"})
CREATE (helen)-[:HAS_PHONE]->(p)
```

This results in a graph that looks like this:

[image]

You can query for business opportunities for Tom (paths that match the pattern you described) like this:

```
MATCH (p:Phone)<-[:HAS_PHONE]-(friend:Person)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-(t:Person {name: "Tom"})-[:HAS_CAR]->(c:Car)
WHERE t.age > 18 AND friend.age > 18
RETURN t.name AS Tom, friend.name AS business_partner, 
    p.desc AS phone, c.desc AS car
```

This query returns:

```
╒═══╤════════════════╤═════════╤══════════════════╕
│Tom│business_partner│phone    │car               │
╞═══╪════════════════╪═════════╪══════════════════╡
│Tom│Helen           │iPhone 6s│2015 Red Honda Fit│
└───┴────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────────┘
```

[Here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/lzak59) is a Neo4j console instance that demonstrates this.

Comment: Oh it works great! Thank you!!! By the way, can it be also done with sparql or swrl rules in protege (just maybe you know)?